# jMeter beanshell - How to calculate a number with milliseconds variable

Tags: jmeter

I have a javaScript variable says:

```
${__javaScript(Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000 -18000 )*1000)}
```

My beanshell code is:

```
start  = vars.get ("startTime-5");
newStart = start + 1000;
```

startTime-5 is the var for the javaScript code.

When I print newStart I expect to get the calculation of start+1000, but instead what I get is adding "1000" as a string.
For example, if start=14456789000 - what I get is 144567890001000 instead of 14456790000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Beanshell Intro](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/intro.html)

> BeanShell emulates typed variables and parameters when they are used. This allows you to "seed" your code with strong types where appropriate. You can "shore up" repeatedly used methods as you work on them, migrating them closer to Java. Eventually you may find that you want to compile these methods and maintain them in standard Java. With BeanShell this is easy. BeanShell does not impose a syntactic boundary between your scripts and Java.

So think of Beanshell as of Java.

Something like:

```
long start = Long.parseLong(vars.get("startTime-5"));
long newStart = start + 1000;

vars.put("newStart", String.valueOf(newStart)); // if you need the JMeter Variable
```

should do the trick for you.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more detailed information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter and for a kind of Beanshell cookbook.